# What would be a performant way to keep single UI element updated depending on a field in each element of a Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application where the `ItemsSource` for several controls is an `ObservableCollection` provided by the ViewModel. The Items (the Class(es) of their Fields - to be precise -)  of the Collection also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` where necessary as the `ObservableCollection` doesn't usually keep track of changes within its contained Items. 
Now I have a Button (or any Control) where its `Button.IsEnabled` depends on a field in *each* of the Items present in the Collection.

Initially, I planned on using a handler for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event which iterates over the whole Collection to check each element for their respective field value to set the `Button.IsEnabled` property accordingly - everytime something gets changed in the possibly huge Collection. This doesn't look like a very performant idea to me.

My ViewModel: `ViewModelClass.cs`

```cs
class ViewModelClass : Window{
   ObservableCollection<DisplayData> list = new ObservableCollection<DisplayData>();

   //constructor
   ViewModelClass{
      list = GetDisplayDataList()
   }

   class DisplayData : INotifyPropertyChanged{
      string Name{get;set;};
      bool DeactivateButton{get;set;};
      // This is simplified, "set" calls NotifyPropertyChanged();

      event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      
      void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname =""){
         if(PropertyChanged != null){ PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname))};
      }
   }
}
```

My UI: `ViewClass.xaml`

```xml
<base:ViewModelClass x:Class="myproject.mynamespace.ViewClass">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Button x:Name="MyButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="Print Error"/>
      <!-- Other UI Elements, eg ListBox where the binding of a whole Collection makes sense--> 
      <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Textblock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
               <!-- etc.-->
            <DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
   </Grid>
</base>
```

`ViewClass.xaml.cs`

```cs
partial class ViewClass : ViewModelClass{
   ViewClass() : base(){
      InitializeComponent();
      Init();
   }

   Init(){
      MyListBox.ItemsSource = base.list;
   }
}
```

In this scenario, is iterating the Collection and checking the DisplayElement.DeactivateButton property my best solution, if the amount of `true` should determine dynamically whether MyButton.IsActivated or not?

Comment: A view model class should not be derived from Window. This looks totally odd.

Comment: well ok, unfortunately thats what I'm working with

Comment: Change it now, before everything gets even worse.

Comment: there is much more to the code already, this is just condensed to my actual question, maybe calling the windows base class viewmodel probably wasn't a good idea.

Comment: If `IsEnabled` depends on all items, how are you supposed to set it without iterating over the whole collection? You may of course use LINQ to simplify the code but you'll still have to iterate.

Comment: thats why i added the ListBox for reference, its items are bound to the collection, and provide means to edit a single item i.e the bool

Comment: nvm ok i guess thats the answer then

Comment: Without a specific performance problem and a specific performance goal, and a good [mcve] demonstrating the scenario, the question is way too broad. That said, if you have a collection of known size, and a flag that depends on the number of elements in that collection having a given state, you can maintain the flag efficiently by also tracking the _count_ of the elements having that state, updating the counter every time any one of the elements changes. For an `&&`, the flag will be set if the counter equals the total number of elements, for an `||`, it will be set if the counter is > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IsEnabled` depends on all items, how are you supposed to set it without iterating over the whole collection? You may of course use LINQ to simplify the code but you'll still have to iterate

Once you have set the initial value, you could handle the `PropertyChanged` event for each item in the collection and make sure that this event gets fired whenever the field changes. <strike>Then you only have to check the current value of the field of the modified item. You can do this in the event handler.</strike>

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsEnabled = collection.All(x => x.field);
}
```

Comment: `IsEnabled = IsEnabled && item.field;` is not going to work. consider a collection of 1 element, which has initial state `false`. after property changes to `true`, IsEnabled still be `false` (`false && true` makes `false`)

Comment: @ASh: Good point :)

Comment: For performantness, he could probably do a count: Initialize it to the count of enabled items in the collection. Decrement when an item goes false, increment when it goes true, `IsEnabled = EnabledItemCount > 0;`. Probably fragile that way. I'd go with `All()`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Me too, unless there is a good reason not to.

Comment: @mm8 Depends how huge "huge" is, but until and unless users complain... All() is fine.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, `IsEnabled = sender.field && collection.All(x => x.field);` will be an `O(1)` operation for every un-check

Comment: Thanks that does look like an awsome solution